# MySQL Query Order By Most Occurrences

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I have a MySQL table, setup like this:

```
id  |  game_type | votes  
01  |  aaa       |  2  
02  |  bbb       |  2  
03  |  ccc       |  4  
04  |  aaa       |  7  
05  |  aaa       |  1  
06  |  ccc       |  11
```

I would like to return all the rows, so they are ordered by game_type, but with the most occurrences of game type in descending order, AND THEN ordered by the amount of voted in descending order, like this:

```
04 aaa  7  
01 aaa  2  
05 aaa  1  
06 ccc  11  
03 ccc  4  
02 bbb  2
```

If I just have the ORDER BY at the end of the query, it just groups them in a random order.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: did you use `ORDER BY game_type ASC, votes DESC`?

Comment: If I have 'ORDER BY game_type ASC, votes DESC' - This will group them all together but alphabetically - not by the count of how many are in that grouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT M.id, M.game_type, M.votes 
FROM MyTable AS M INNER JOIN
    (SELECT game_type, COUNT(game_Type) AS TypeCount
     FROM MyTable
     GROUP BY game_type
     ORDER BY COUNT(game_Type) DESC) AS U
  ON M.game_type=U.game_type
ORDER BY U.TypeCount DESC, M.game_type, M.votes DESC
```

Comment: Brilliant! Just one more thing. This orders the game_type with the lowest count at the top. For some reason when I change the above code from ORDER BY COUNT(game_Type) ASC --> ORDER BY COUNT(game_Type) DESC - This does not change the order, any ideas why?

Comment: @badgers, Oops, my mistake.  You need to change it for both the U SELECT and the outer SELECT.  That last order should be `U.TypeCount DESC`  I updated my answer.  (Acutually, I don't know if I really need the `ORDER BY COUNT(game_Type)` statement but I didn't have time to test it.

Comment: Great stuff, thats perfect. Thanks for your help

Comment: Note that the inner `ORDER BY` is only relevant for performance, if at all. It has no influence at all on the overall result.

Comment: Great to hear.  As you are new to StackOverflow, it is customary to mark the answer as "Answered" by checking the checkmark next to the answer so that others know this was accepted.  Thanks.